# Is O(n^3) really more efficient than O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

My algorithm class's homework claims that O(n<sup>3</sup>) is more efficient than O(2<sup>n</sup>).

When I put these functions into a graphing calculator, f(x)=2<sup>x</sup> appears to be consistently more efficient for very large n (starting from around n = 982).

Considering that for a function f(n) = O(g(n)), it must be smaller for all n greater than some n<sub>0</sub>, wouldn't this mean that from n = 982 we could say that O(2<sup>n</sup>) is more efficient?

Comment: A calculator is no substitute for actually learning math.

Comment: 2^982 is about 40 billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion billion [continues until 98 "billion"s]. 982^3 is about a billion. Would you rather something take a billion steps, or 40 billion billion billion billion billion...?

Comment: Yes it is.  With a pencil and paper, draw a graph of N^3 versus 2^N.  For large enough values of N.  (Your calculator is probably screwing up because of overflow.  2^982 is too large for a typical calculator!)  For extra points, prove it mathematically.  (Hint: by induction ...)

Comment: (correction - 40 million billion billion billion [continues until 32 "billion"s])

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your graphing calculator was showing you and how you drew this conclusion from it?

Comment: @templatetypedef After checking on other calculators, there seems to be something wrong with the one I was using. Thanks.

Comment: @n.m. If you have any suggestions for specific points I should review, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: 2^10 is slightly greater than 1000. 2^30 is greater than 1000^3. 982^3 is less than 1000^3. 2^982 is vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly greater than 2^30. Since 1000=10^3, n=10 is about the point where 2^n takes over n^3 for good. If you don't have all of the above in your subconsciousness, you have a problem as a math/CS/programming student. Do whatever it takes to fix it.

Comment: If this question was asked in a way that made sense, it would probably be a duplicate of [Can an O(n) algorithm ever exceed O(n^2) in terms of computation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594174/can-an-on-algorithm-ever-exceed-on2-in-terms-of-computation-time)

Comment: All polynomial functions are more efficient (faster in performance) than exponential functions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`2^n` grows extremely faster than `n^3`. Maybe you have input wrong values into your calculator or something like that. Also note that **more efficient** means **less time** which means a **lower value** on the `y-axis`.

Let me show you some correct plots for those functions (using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%5En,%20n%5E3)):

[image: early course of 2^n and n^3]

**First** `2^n` is *smaller* (but just for a tiny range), **after that** you can see how `2^n` grows beyond it.

After this intersection the situation never changes again and `2^n` remains extremely greater than `n^3`. That also holds for the range you analysed, so **> 982**, like seen in the next plot (the plot for `n^3` is near the `x-axis`):

[image: 2^n extremely greater than n^3]

---

Also note that in the **Big-O-Notation** we always compare functions based on their growth. This is why something like `O(n^3)` does not contain functions `f : f(x) <= n^3` but rather `f : f(x) <= C * n^3` where `C` is an arbitrary constant, it could be big, it could be small. This accounts for the **growth-factor** in the comparison. Also note that it is allowed that the condition does not hold for a finite amount of `x` but there must exist some bound `x'` from where on the condition holds, so for every `x > x'`.

Compare this explanation to the complete mathematical definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) where `C` is `k`, `x` is `n` and `x'` is `n_0`:

[image: definition of Big-O]

Which defines, if true, that `f(n)` is in the set `O(g(n))`.

Comment: As a note I'd like to add that this hidden constant factor `C` could be a reason why an algorithm that runs in `O(2^n)` indeed could be faster for inputs of a practical range than one running in `O(n^3)`. It could be that the second algorithm has an extreme overhead with a hidden constant `C = 1_000_000` or something very big. However `O-Notation` means: *"at some point, where inputs get really large, the `O(2^n)` will be slower than `O(n^3)`"*. But again, as said, it could be possible that the other algorithms runs faster for smaller inputs that could also exactly be all **relevant inputs**.

Answer (score 2):

You confuse O(2<sup>n</sup>) and 2<sup>n</sup>. O(2<sup>n</sup>) is actually C*2<sup>n</sup>, where C is an arbitrary chosen positive constant. Likewise, O(n<sup>3</sup>) is D*n<sup>3</sup>, where D is another arbitrary chosen positive constant. The claim "O(n<sup>3</sup>) is more efficient than O(2<sup>n</sup>)" means that, given any fixed C and D, it is always possible to find such n<sub>0</sub> that for any n >= n<sub>0</sub>, D*n<sup>3</sup>
 < C*2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: Given just how extreme the growth of 2^n is and how strange the 982 number in the question is, I think the confusion goes deeper than that.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair enough.

Comment: Assuming C and D to be similar, both algorithms would have a similar performance for around 10 items.